How to tint SFSymbol when displaying using UIImage?
How do I get the SFSymbol to show with the specified tint color against the black background of the VStack?
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            createHelloWorldView(image: UIImage(systemName: "airplane.circle.fill")!.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate), hello: "Hello", world: "World")
        }
        .background {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func createHelloWorldView(image: UIImage, hello: String, world: String) -> some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        
        Text(hello)
            .font(.title)
        
        Text(world)
            .font(.title2)
    }
}

Edit: In the actual code I can only pass in a UIImage object for the Image to display hence the color setting has to be done to the UIImage itself.
Any help is appreciated.

Try setting .foregroundStyle(.white) on the Image (or on the VStack, both work)

The code above is a stripped down version of the actual. In the actual code I can only pass in a UIImage object for the Image to display hence the color setting has to be done to the UIImage itself. I've updated my question to mention that.

Passing around the UIImage will remove the customizations this is a known limitation. It would be best to pass around the name vs the UIImage

One workaround would be to create an Image view in the usual way (using foregroundStyle to set the color), then convert the View to UIImage using an ImageRenderer. See the (later) answers to How to convert an Image to UIImage? for details.
